# c# How to add up total of protected array

Tags: c#, arrays, protected

I'm trying to add the complete total of all TotalPrice for the 5 inputs, when I add this:

```
for(x= 0; x < InputOrder.Length; ++x){
Console.WriteLine("Total is ${0}", InputOrder[x].TotalPrice++);
```

I get an error message when compiling:

error CS0200: Property or indexer 'System.Order.TotalPrice 
cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

When I write it like this it compiles and the output is correct, it just seems like there is a much better way to do it

```
Console.WriteLine("Total is ${0}", 
 (InputOrder[0].TotalPrice + 
  InputOrder[1].TotalPrice + 
  InputOrder[2].TotalPrice + 
  InputOrder[3].TotalPrice + 
  InputOrder[4].TotalPrice));
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old school:

```
int total = 0;
for(x= 0; x < InputOrder.Length; ++x){
    total += InputOrder[x].TotalPrice;

Console.WriteLine("Total is ${0}", total);
```

LINQ:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total is ${0}", InputOrder.Sum(item => item.TotalPrice));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine("Total is ${0}", InputOrder.Sum(x=>x.TotalPrice));
```

It's not array, it's Your InputOrder.TotalPrice which is protected

Comment: You don't need the for loop if you use the LINQ expression.

Comment: @Oded copy+paste mistake... at start there were no LINQ